# How to make a copy by value of a generic type parameter

Tags: go, generics

In a generic function, how can I copy by value a parameter with a generic type ?

Here is a minimal example :

```golang
type MyInterface interface { // Interface use for type constraint
    SetID(string)
}

type Implem struct { // Implements MyInterface
    ID string
}

func (i *Implem) SetID(id string) {
    i.ID = id
}

func doStuff[T MyInterface](input T) T {
    res := input // Here I want to make a copy of input, so the next line modify res but not input
    res.SetID("newID")
    return res
}

func main() {
    implem := &Implem{ID: "oldID"}
    res := doStuff(implem)
    fmt.Println(implem) // Should be "oldID"
    fmt.Println(res)    // Should be "newID"
}
```

I tried several things, like declaring `res` as a `*T` and setting input as its value, or playing with type assertions, but `SetID` still modify input.

What is the best way to copy `input` by value ?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/1qQu46qYIKW

Comment: @mkopriva thanks, it works well. Is there any way to do something similar on a method instead of a function ?

Comment: For methods the type parameters need to be declared in the receiver's type declaration, rather than the method itself. This also means that, to call the method, you'll first need an instance of the receiver, but instantiation of generic types (rather than generic functions) requires that you provide the type arguments explicitly (i.e., there's no type inference). And, once you have an instance of the receiver, the method will only accept the values of the type argument specified during the instantiation of the receiver's generic type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general case, shallow copying type parameters works the same as with whatever type argument was used to instantiate it. If you instantiate `T` with a non-pointer type, an assignment copies its value. If you instantiate `T` with a pointer type, an assignment still copies its value, but that value is a memory address.

In the code you wrote, the type constraint `MyInterface` could be satisfied by both pointer and non-pointer types.

Hypothetically, you could declare a type like:

```
type Foo struct{}

func (i Implem) SetID(id string) {
}
```

Any assignment on fields of a value receiver would be ineffective, but `Foo` would be a valid type argument.

Perhaps what you want to do is to restrict the type parameter to pointer types. This way you can capture the base type and dereference to shallow copy the value.

```
// restrict to pointer types
type MyInterface[T any] interface {
    *T
    SetID(string)
}

// capture the base type T
// the argument 'input' is a pointer type due to MyInterface
func doStuff[T any, U MyInterface[T]](input U) U {
    t := *input        // dereferencing copies the value
    res := U(&t)       // take address of t and convert to U
    res.SetID("newID") // you can now call SetID on value of type U
    return res
}
```

And this outputs

```
&{oldID}
&{newID}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/U8Ssq3_YPVi

---

As an alternative, you can add an additional method to your struct that returns a copy of it. Then within the generic function, you type assert to an anonymous interface that has that method:

```
// shallow copy and return same type
func (i *Implem) Copy() *Implem {
    c := *i
    return &c
}

func doStuff[T MyInterface](input T) T {
    // type assert to anonymous interface with method that returns T
    t, ok := any(input).(interface{ Copy() T })
    if !ok {
        // handle failure
    }
    res := t.Copy()
    res.SetID("newID")
    return res
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/K7MOApHdEmM

Using an anonymous interface in my opinion makes it more convenient and readable, as the type parameter `T` is used in a self-explanatory way. You can of course define a named interface:

```
type Copier[T any] interface {
    Copy() T
}
```

and assert to that interface instantiated with `T`:

```
t, ok := any(input).(Copier[T])
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/Berisu6Qz-P